# Корректная выборка подстроки

Tags: php

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, найти решение.
Понятно, что вопрос относится к разряду "сделайте за меня", не прошу решения готового, хотябы идею, какой функцией или каким способом, методом лучше и проще будет это реализовать.

Имеется элемент массива:

```
$key = 'NAME'; $value = 'ао ОАО "ТГК-2"';
```

Необходимо выпилить из значения все то, что будет следовать перед сокращением **ОАО**, хотя может встретится и **ООО** или **ИП** или **ЧПУП** или любое другое сокращение, а также после названия организации **"ТГК-2"** хотя может встретится любое другое название организации.

Одно знаю точно, что вариантов только два, это сочетание "ао" или "ап":

*первый вариант:*

```
$key = 'NAME'; $value = 'ап ОАО "ТГК-2"'; // перед сокращением ОАО "ап "
$key = 'NAME'; $value = 'ао ОАО "ТГК-2"'; // перед сокращением ОАО "ао "
```

*второй вариант:*

```
$key = 'NAME'; $value = 'ОАО "ТГК-2" ап'; // после "ТГК-2"(или другое название) " ап"
$key = 'NAME'; $value = 'ОАО "ТГК-2" ао'; // после "ТГК-2"(или другое название) " ао"
```

Comment: @archi_sova, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Shrek этот вопрос не относится к учебному заданию

Comment: @archi_sova по идее данный код должен хавать любые комбинации. Я бы посоветовал проверить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуйтесь на здоровье!

```
$value[] = 'ап ОАО "ТГК-2"'; 
$value[] = 'ао ОАО "ТГК-2"'; 
$value[] = 'ОАО "ТГК-2" ап'; 
$value[] = 'ОАО "ТГК-2" ао'; 
$value[] = 'ОАО "ТГК-2" ап';
$value[] = 'ОАО "ТГК-2" ао';
$value[] = 'Сбербанк России ОАО ао';
$value[] = 'ОАО Сбербанк России ао';
$value[] = '"КрасныйОктябрь" ОАО - ао';
$value[] = 'ОАО "КрасныйОктябрь" - ао';

// Сбербанк России ОАО ао
$array[0] = '(.*)\s+([А-Я]{2,})\s*(?:ап|ао)';

// ОАО "КрасныйОктябрь" - ао
$array[1] = '"(.*?)"\s*([А-Я]*)\s*\W*\s*(?:ап|ао)';

// ао ОАО "ТГК-2" | ао ОАО ТГК-2
$array[2] = '(?:ап|ао)\s*([А-Я]*)\s+"?(.*?)"?$';

// "КрасныйОктябрь" ОАО - ао
$array[3] = '([А-Я]*)\s*"?(.*?)"?\s*(?:\W|)\s*(?:ап|ао)';

echo "<pre>\n";
echo '/(?:'.implode('|', $array).')/'."\n";

foreach($value as $ArrList) {
    /**
     * ищем ищем
     */
    preg_match('/(?:'.implode('|', $array).')/', $ArrList, $match);

    echo "//-------------------------\n\n\n";

    // т.к. регулярка выдает разные массивы для разных обрывков, то для идентификации будем еще раз проверять на вхождение, а как иначе то?
    foreach($array as $ArrKey => $ArrMatch) {
        if(preg_match('/'.$ArrMatch.'/', $ArrList)) {
            if($ArrKey == '0') {
                $return = array($match[2], $match[1]);
            }
            elseif($ArrKey == '1') {
                if(empty($match[7])) {
                    $return = array($match[4], $match[3]);
                }
                else {
                    $return = array($match[7], $match[8]);
                }
            }
            elseif($ArrKey == '2') {
                $return = array($match[5], $match[6]);
            }
            elseif($ArrKey == '3') {
                $return = array($match[7], $match[8]);
            }
            break;
        }
        // упс
    }

    var_dump($return);
}
```

Comment: @archi_sova ясное дело не будет работать, т.к. отсутствуют кавычки. Без кавычек уже сложно определить, где заканчивается одно и начинается другое. Или же у вас не целые предложения, а просто обрывки?

Comment: обрывки вот такого плана:
*вот так*
 **[SECNAME] => ао ОАО "ТГК-2"**
*или так*
 **[SECNAME] => Сбербанк России ОАО ао**
*или так*
 **[SECNAME] => "КрасныйОктябрь" ОАО - ао**

Comment: @archi_sova я обновил пост.

Comment: А подскажите как можно составить универсальное выражение например для такого случая, когда нужно удалить либо первые три символа, либо последние три символа, это я к тому что названий может быть тысяча не только те которые я указал, а всего два случая! первые три символа или последние три символа. :) ну и чтобы оно как-то определяло удаление, ну типо если наше ао или ап в начале значит удаляй из начала, ну а если в начале нету значит удаляй с конца.

Comment: $str = substr($str,0,-N) - удаление последних N символов. $rest = $str = substr($str, N) - удаление первых N символов.

Comment: Приведите пример, где содержится название. Я просто не пойму, откуда вам нужно вытаскивать слова. И регулярка, что в обновленном после не подходит?

Comment: Ваши выражения подходят только для перечисленных выше? или для любого имени, т.е. комбинация может любая, главное чтобы ао и ап было в начале или в конце? Самое название содержится в элементе массива  [SECNAME], ну т.е. как бы надо составить что-то типо этого **(ао|ап)(любое имя)(ао|ап)**, а потом вывести только **(любое имя)**